# does title bar gets some space of jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating a snake game where I'm using a `JFrame` with the size of `600x600`, but its real area where I can paint is a little bit smaller.

When I try to draw a pixel in the bottom right corner, it appears behind the window border.

I created my `JFrame` like this:

```
public class Problem {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Snake snake = new Snake();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("Snake");
            gameWindow.add(snake);
            gameWindow.setSize(600, 600);
            gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gameWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gameWindow.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private static class Snake extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawLine(599, 599, 599, 599);
    }
}
```

}

How can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previos solution was correct, but I've modified my code to be better suitable to your example. What you should do is to set the preferred size for your Snake object, add it to frame and call pack for your frame (order is important!).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("Snake");
                snake.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
                gameWindow.add(snake);
                gameWindow.pack();
                gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                gameWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                gameWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Snake extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D.drawOval(549, 549, 50, 50);
        }
    }
```

I've changed your Snake object to draw a circle, because it better shows frame borders. Your implementation has drawn a point (not a line!) in the right bottom edge of frame, that is difficult to see.
    }

Comment: I edited my question by adding code which ilustrates my problem. Even if i draw point on 599,599 it is still behind border of my window

Comment: @wariat I've changed my answer

Comment: Okay, it solved my problems :)  Can u tell me shortly why my code didn't work properly?

Comment: @wariat Because your code doesn't consider the frame borders added by OS. So the `pack` method of a frame is the preferred variant to set the frame bounds. But this method works correctly only when frame is filled with all components.